# XAML designer does not load when using subclass of a UserControl

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

I created a subclass **MyUserControl** that extend the built-in **UserControl** to shared some common fields and functions among some widgets. However, after Visual Studio restarted, I found that all XAML using the MyUserControl class instead of the original UserControl does not have the XAML designer loaded correctly. Those xaml files are treated like normal xml file without auto complete. There is no split view (designer on top and code at bottom). While the code is working, it is very inconvenient.

The subclass is actually doing some event-Action subscription and handling so its not something that can easily be replaced by extension methods externally.

How do I make it work without breaking the XAML designer? Am I extending the UserControl the wrong way or just missing something to make the designer work as before?

Thanks